# Kafka giving warn failed to send SSL close message

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka cluster of 3 kafka brokers on 3 different servers.

Lets assume the three servers are .

```
99.99.99.1 
99.99.99.2
99.99.99.3
```

All 3 servers have a shared path on which kafka is residing.

I have created 3 server.properties with name

```
server1.properties
server2.properties
server3.properties
```

The server1.properties look like below:

```
broker.id=1
port=9094
listeners=SSL://99.99.99.1:9094
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=3
zookeeper.connect=99.99.99.1:2181,99.99.99.2:2182,99.99.99.3:2183
ssl.keystore.location=xyz.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.truststore.location=xyz.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.client.auth=required
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
```

Similarly, the other two server properties look.

**Issues/Query:**

1. I need the consumer and producer should connect using SSL and even all the brokers should connect to each other using SSL. Is my configuration right for this?
2. I keep on getting below error is this usual?

   WARN Failed to send SSL Close message
   (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
   java.io.IOException: Broken pipe